# How to return the object that holds a class java

Tags: java, class, object

I have a class World that holds a class object named Player and I would like to be able to inside Player to be able to create an object of the class holding the object. Does what I am saying make sense? Is what im saying possible?

edit:Also Player is abstract and I get an error in the child class when I put some of your code in

Comment: Make the question more clear,, please.

Comment: Classes don't 'hold class objects'. 'To inside Player be able to create an object of the class holding the object' makes a small amount of sense but not enough for an answer. Try again. Or else the answer is just `new World()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a reference named `parent`, and assign it upon creation.  Then, you could use reflection to figure out exactly what that `parent`'s class is.

```
public class Player{
    private Object parent;
    public Player(Object parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Class getParentClass(){
        return parent.getClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use reflection in this case? Seems like the wrong tool for the job. Also the code sample doesnt display reflection at all.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but it seemed like he wanted to not only have a reference to the parent object, but also to its class.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the world object to the constructor of player

```
public class World{
  public World(){
    new Player(this);
  }
}
public class Player{
  private World world;
  public Player(World world){
    this.world = world;
  }
}
```

now you can use the world inside the player with `world`